# How to supply a microphone with plug-in-power via TRS or TRRS plug?

Tags: microphone, power, phantom, plug-in

I would like to use a [Rode VideoMicro](http://en.rode.com/microphones/videomicro) microphone requiring low-voltage phantom power, or [plug-in power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_power#Other_microphone_powering_techniques), on a device which does not supply plug-in-power. There seem to be [commercial](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072R3RD11) [options](https://www.makerhart.com/product_d.php?lang=en&tb=1&id=7), though I would like to DIY a tiny, cheap version for my use-case.

What circuit is needed to supply the microphone with the needed 1.5-5v? Does either of these [circuits](http://www.richardmudhar.com/articles/sound-recording-guide/pip.html) [below](https://www.bytebang.at/Blog/Aviation+Headset+to+USB+Adapter) work?

[image: Plug-in-power diagram]
[image: Aviation-headset adapter]

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It would work in the sense you will successfully apply a bias voltage to the capsule and get audio frequency signal out of it.  If inserting a bunch of hand-assembled noise sources into the system results in a better final product than buying a potentially 'lower quality' mic capsule that has the right feature set for the application is uncertain.

Comment: Context on the application would help, is this a field biology project on a budget and you want to run dozens of these for a week off a battery pack?  You already own the mic and someone gifted you an incompatible camera?

Comment: Ok, the context is a bit special: My convertible car's stereo with hands-free calling is very noisy, especially with the top down. The included microphone is an extremely cheap microphone, the default one you get with just about every car stereo. Therefore I am trying to improve the microphone quality using a directional microphone with an added deadcat. Futile? Yes. Fun? Yes. I posted the question here and got answers: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/567048/how-to-supply-a-microphone-with-plug-in-power-via-trs-or-trrs-plug